# How does DataTable drawCallback work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to apply `CSS` to each of the `DataTable` cells based on its value, using the `drawCallback()`.The CSS gets applied to a few cells and not all. Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3tapzpj/) to my issue.Has anyone come across this issue and found a solution or have any ideas on this.Please suggest!

```
  "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        var api = this.api();
        var visibleRows=api.rows( {page:'current'} ).data();
        if(visibleRows.length >= 1){
        for(var j=1;j<visibleRows[visibleRows.length -1].length;j++){
          $("td:eq("+j+")", settings.nTBody.childNodes[visibleRows.length -1]).addClass(visibleRows[visibleRows.length -1][j]);
        }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Might look at row render callback https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html Not clear what your objective is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @charlietfl said, you don't really want to be using `drawCallback` to format the rows, and you would probably be better off using `createdRow` (rowCallback) to do this formatting.

`drawCallback` is called on every draw event, meaning that it's really meant to be used to update rows that have just been added or work with data that has just been updated.

`createdRow` on the other hand, is designed to be called whenever a row is created, which seems to be what you really want. In [this documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) ([example](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html)), you can see that the author displays how to use this option to add a class to certain rows, which seems to be the closest to what you want to do.

As far as I can tell, you want to make every cell have a CSS class that is the same as the text in the cell (correct me if I'm wrong). The easiest way to do that with `createdRow` would be as follows:

```
"createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
    for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
        $('td', row).eq(i).addClass(data[i]);
        //The above line assumes that you want to add a CSS class named "red" to a 
        //field that has the text "red" in it, if not, you can change the logic
    }
}
```

Just include this in your initialization options for the `.DataTables()` call.

I had to make some assumptions about the exact logic for what classes get added to what columns, but if they are correct, then this should add a class to each field that is named the same as the text in that field.